# Select rows that has mixed charcters in a single value e.g. 'Joh?n' in name column

Tags: sql, oracle

In an oracle table:

1- a value in a VARCHAR column contains characters that are not letters.

Consider a scenarion where a name in 'last_name' column contains regular characters (A - Z, a - z) as well as characters that are not english letters (e.g. '.', '-', ' ','_', '>' or similar).

The challenge is to select the rows that has names in 'last_name' as '.John' or 'John.' or '-John' or 'Joh-n'

2- Is it possible to have non-date values in a Date defined column?  If yes, how can such records be selected in an oracle query?

Thanks!

Comment: For #2, a column of type DATE can only hold valid dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will do the trick:

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(last_name, '[^A-Za-z]');`

As for your 2nd question, I am unsure. I would be glad if someone else could add on to what I have to answer your 2nd question. I have found this website thought that might be of help. http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-time.html
It explains the DATE format.

Comment: Thanks Zzyrk!  Can I also include a space that need not be find?  I mean 'John Doe' as in name column is a ligit value.  I mean space in between a first name and last name is a ligit character.  How do I include a space in the list '[^A-Za-z]'.  Many thanks.

Comment: The `^` negates the set therfore matching anything not enclosed in the brackets. So it will catch any name that has any caracter different than a letter. Many websites will help you create your regex. Example : http://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html

Comment: Sorry, I just caught on. You dont want to catch the spaces... you can add a space in the set like this and it should work. `^[A-Za-z ]`

Answer (score 0):

If I properly understand your goal, you need to select rows with last_name column containing the name 'John', but it may also have additional characters before, after, or even inside the name. In that case, this should be helpful:

```
select * from tab where regexp_replace(last_name, '[^A-Za-z]+', '') = 'John'
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I ran the queery, it pulled the records, but changed all the names that qualify the criteria to 'John'. I guess, I should explain that I am looking for all the records in the table that has invalid characters (see example in the original question) in the name, not just one specific name. lmk if this helps!